# Executing jar file from protractor

Tags: protractor

I am trying to execute command "java -jar mytest.jar" using child_process inside my spec file of protractor. Code is getting executed but nothing is happening.

With successful execution it will create new file. Pls help me to resolve this.

Below is my code:

```
it('execute Jar', ()=>{
    let exec = require('child_process').exec;
    const child = exec("java -jar mytest.jar", (error, stdout, stderr)=>{
        if (error) {
            console.error('exec error: ${error}');
            return;
          }
          console.log('stdout: ${stdout}');
          console.log('stderr: ${stderr}');
    });

});
```

Node code which executed and returns as expected

```
let exec = require('child_process').exec;
let childprocess = exec("java -jar mytest.jar",
                 function (err, stdout, stderr){
                   if (err){
                     console.log(err);
                   }
                   console.log(stdout);
                 });
```